# LVM volume mapped block device size is 0

Tags: lvm, ext2

I'm having a problem with my LVM volume. I lost a disk out of my RAID array, and started in in degraded mode. Now when I try to access 2 of the LVM volumes, they report a block size of 0. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
$ lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Name             /dev/vg0/home
VG Name             vg0
...
LV Size             20.00 GiB
```

---

```
$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/vg0-root
0
```

---

```
$ mount /dev/mapper/vg0-root /mnt
mount: /dev/mapper/vg0-root: can't read superblock
```

---

```
$mke2fs -n /dev/mapper/vg0-root
mke2fs 1.41-14 (22-Dec-2010)
mke2fs: Device size reported to be zero. Invalid partition specified, or
        partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
        a modified partition being busy and in use. You may need to reboot
        to re-ready your partition table.
```

Comment: are you sure you lvm volumes are ok? use lvs +ao devices

Answer (score 0):

I retested with a newer linux kernel and the issue went away. Maybe this was an old bug that has been fixed.